# Context Menu updating on Key Events of Textbox - Windows Form

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, textbox, contextmenu

Auto complete Property of `Textbox` is not satisfying my requirement as I want to display all options in dropdown initially and when textbox is empty.

So I thought of Context Menu.

It should be something like this. 
I m subscribing two events of `TextBox`, `KeyDown` and `KeyUp`. 
Assuming `KeyDown` will raise first and then `KeyUp`. **So on every KeyUp, I m loading Context Menu as per TextBox's Text and showing dropdown and on Every KeyDown (assuming user is still inputting) Sending `Esc` key to close dropdown [and on upcoming KeyUp event it will show proper dropdown]**
Putting my code below.

```
        void txtIndi2_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            mnuIndi2.MenuItems.Clear();
            foreach (string indi in IndicatorList)
            {
                if (txtIndi2.Text == "" || indi.ToLower().StartsWith(txtIndi2.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    MenuItem mnuItmIndi2 = new MenuItem(indi);
                    mnuItmIndi2.Click += mnuItmIndi2_Click;
                    mnuIndi2.MenuItems.Add(mnuItmIndi2);
                    //indiOptions.Add(indi);
                }
            }
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Log.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("KeyUp " + txtIndi2.Text);
            }

            mnuIndi2.Show(txtIndi2, new Point(0, txtIndi2.Location.Y + 20));
            txtIndi2.Focus();
        }

        void txtIndi2_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Log.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("KeyDown " + txtIndi2.Text);
            }
            SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");
        }
```

Logs seems correct if I remove Context Menu showing and Sending Esc key related code, meaning flow and sequence is correct.
But with the code shown above, It is not raising event only first time. if I try to type "open" logs will be like

```
> KeyDown 
> KeyUp o 
> KeyUp o
```

I Think it is because, once dropdown is shown, focus goes away from textbox, but I programmatically tried to put focus on textbox after displaying dropdown. So on Next trial of typing `KeyDown` should be raised. But It is not being raised.

Guide me with what I m doing wrong here.

Comment: instead of listening to 3 event why don't listen to Textbox change event. on textchange just reload the dropdown according to u vr condition.

Comment: @RaviKanth I need dropdown keep in display if user is not further typing in TextBox, as soon as user start typing further, dropdown should be updated accordingly. Now on TextChange event Dropdown is perfect for fist time (one first letter) but then it is not being typed on textbox neither dropdown is being updated